# How can I get a rewritten render_to_response to get a json in django with the least changes to the whole project

Tags: python, django

I now receive a task, that is developing a native app on phone based on a web project. So I think the best way to communicate between server and client is using json.

Then I need all the response give me a result of json format. But now in the web project, almost every view use `render_to_response` like the following:

```
ctxt = RequestContext(request,*args)
return render_to_response('XXX.html',ctxt)
```

Then I want rewrite render_to_response like below, so I need not to change every one to a new function:

```
def render_to_response:
  return new HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(*args), mimetype='text/json'))
```

Obviously, I can change the source code in django, but it's not a practicable method. Because other project also need use it.

Or I can write a new module with the `render_to_response` function, and import this after

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
```

But I am not sure if this is possible.

If this can work, I also need to add this import into every `.py` files which is still a huge work.

So I want a best way with the least changes to the whole project.

Comment: Try a middleware perhaps?

Comment: I have thought about this, but in `process_response`, `response` is already html.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `return` you have with this

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctxt), content_type="application/json")
```

On a different note, you do not really need to return the context if the client requesting it doesn't need it. You might be better of return a simple message like "Success"

Another solution is to include `django-annoying` in your project and use the `@ajax_request`  decorator on all your views which want to respond as json.

```
@ajax_request
def my_view(request):
    news = News.objects.all()
    news_titles = [entry.title for entry in news]
    return {'news_titles': news_titles}
```

Refer example here - https://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/wiki/Home

Comment: But in my project, there is  a great quantity `return` I need to replace, what I want is a magic way I do the least changes.

Comment: Add the `@ajax_request` decorator to all your views. You cannot return render_to_response since that returns the html, just replace it with return context and use the `ajax_request` decorator.