# How to get dictionary of RequestContext imported from django.template

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in my django project.

```
ctxt = RequestContext(request, {
    'power': power,
    'attack': attack,
    'defense': defense,
    })
```

Now I want get this dictionary like below through `ctxt`

```
{
    'power': power,
    'attack': attack,
    'defense': defense,
}
```

I tried `ctxt.dicts`, but this contains too many items. So I see into the source code, and find these code in `class RequestContext(Context):`

```
for processor in get_standard_processors() + processors:
    self.update(processor(request))
```

which I think bring in the other items.

So how can I get that?

Btw, if you want to know why I want to do this, you can see this question I asked before.

[How can I get a rewritten render_to_response to get a json in django with the least changes to the whole project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394376/how-can-i-get-a-rewritten-render-to-response-to-get-a-json-in-django-with-the-le)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ctxt.dict is stack of dictionaries, so you only need to:

```
ctxt.dict[0]
```

Comment: ctxt.dicts[0] works in django 1.11.  Using 'dict' generates the error: AttributeError: 'RequestContext' object has no attribute 'dict'

Comment: ctxt.flatten() is a way better method imho

Comment: Won't this solution only retrieve a subpart of the context?

Answer (score 18):

I'm a bit late to the party, but you can get a dict from your RequestContext object with

```
ctxt.flatten()
```

if you're using Django>=1.7. [(Docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context.flatten)

Comment: If you are pulling the context from a Django tag; then using `select_template` or `get_template`; then use flatten `template.render(context.flatten())`